# My Temptation theme is showing two of the same menu at the top. How do I remove the one that the theme comes with? Please help!

Tags: menus, css, mobile

I've tried the CSS that someone else posted but it didn't work. I can't find the option to remove one of the menus. It's not showing on mobile, but it shows up on the desktop site. My website is www.sonomalogistics.com

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Hi KYLE COTT, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers third-party theme questions off-topic so you might notice some down-votes. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fairly easy to figure out this one if you read around.

You'd need to login to your site dashboard as admin -> `site.com/wp-admin`, Navigate further to `Appearance -> Menus` from left side menu bar.

In Menu section you need to create 2 Menus for your Top Menu and Header Menu. Top menu can be disabled if there are no pages added to it but Header menu seems to always show at least one page, you can try and figure this out.

Add no pages to the top menu. Once you save the two menus and select appropriate locations for them, changes should be visible on the site.
[image: Menu Settings in back-end]
[image]